# Jupyter notebooks with rstudio-server open source

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, rstudio-server

Is it possible to use Jupyter notebooks with the open source version of rstudio-server? I was unable to find any documentation regarding this except for this link which talks about rstudio-server pro.

```
     https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.2.5001-3/jupyter-sessions.html
```

Please point me to a link if anybody has already implemented this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use Jupyter Notebooks in the Open Source version of RStudio Server. This is a feature that requires RStudio Launcher and it and requires RStudio Server Pro.

It's possible to try RStudio Server Pro for 45 days, with no strings attached.
You can just follow the docs to start your trial:

1. https://docs.rstudio.com/rsp/installation/
2. https://docs.rstudio.com/rsp/integration/jupyter-standalone/

If you are looking for other OSS options you can take a look at JupyterHub and how it supports RStudio IDE inside their architecture.

(Disclaimer I work for RStudio)

Comment: There you have it

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Jupyter has current implementation for running inside of R Studio Community.

Comment: this is for setting up an R kernel inside of jupyter notebook. The question is using jupyter notebooks from R Studio srvr

Comment: @thus__ I don't believe Jupyter has current implementation for running inside of R Studio.

Comment: the link you provided reviews setting up an R kernel in jupyter notebook within a Docker container. The thread ends with a link to [nbrsessionproxy](https://github.com/jupyterhub/nbrsessionproxy) which allows for running RStudio sessions from Jupyter.